# Is it viable using sstableloader to clone data from Cassandra 4.x back to Cassandra 3.x?

Tags: cassandra

I learned that Cass 4.x is compatible to sstables from Cass3.x.

*Cassandra 4.1 (which has version -nb- ) is able to read SSTable formats as early as -ma- (from C* 3.0. 0).*

So I assume that I can use sstable to clone data from a cass 3.0 to a cass 4.0 of a new cluster. [How do I migrate data in tables to a new Cassandra cluster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316520/how-do-i-migrate-data-in-tables-to-a-new-cassandra-cluster)) (Much thanks to Erick, the attributor to this doc)

Then, here's the question: Does this clone procedure work good when I trying to clone from a cass 4 to a cass 3.

I guess the core of this question is: does cass 3.x. sstable work fine on a cass 4.x.